# Widget size decreasing while changing the orientation

Tags: android, layout, widget

I have created a WiFi Widget. Its size is decreasing while changing the orientation from Portrait to Landscape. 
The layout I am using is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />

<!--<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

 -->
</LinearLayout>
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_off"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15dip"
     />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_notconnected"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_marginTop="43dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="14dip" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_connecting"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="33dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="14dip" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_obtaining"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_on"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="10dip"
     />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_signal_strength"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip">

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_circle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/onpress_network_info_null"
    android:src="@drawable/toggle"
    />

   <ImageView
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/wifi_circle"
        android:id="@+id/wifi_square"
        android:layout_width="85dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip" 
        android:background="@drawable/network_info_null"
        android:src="@drawable/togglenetwork"/>

     </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
 </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want this layout both Portrait and Landscape** then you write hard code on oncreate like this:- 
There will be a time you need to define your application GUI both in landscape and portrait (just rotate the phone).

Luckily, every droid has the built-in function to detect layout type. What you need to implement is:

1. Create two main.xml files for layout in both case: landscape and portrait.
2. Put those two main.xml in resources according to its type:

   > /res/layout-land/main.xml
   >
   > /res/layout-port/main.xml

Just build and try your application GUI in runtime.

In case, you want to detect the timing when layout type change and you want to do some additional works in coding, you might wanna follow these steps:

1. Add android:configChanges=”orientation” to AndroidManifest.xml
2. Detect the orientation change:

> @Override
>
> ```
> public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
>   Configuration c = getResources().getConfiguration();
>
>   if(c.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ) {
>     // portrait
>
>   } else if(c.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ){
>     // landscape
>
>   }   }
> ```

[Details](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/detect-layout-type-landscapeportrait/)

**If you want only portrait, then**

> ```
> AndroidManifest.xml, declare your Activity like so: <activity ...    android:screenOrientation="portrait" .../>
> ```

**If you want only landscape, then**

> ```
>  AndroidManifest.xml, declare your Activity like so: <activity ...     android:screenOrientation="landscape" .../>
> ```

If you want more information, Please go to these links

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

[StackOverflow search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D%20how%20to%20make%20programmatically%20portate%20and%20landscape&submit=search)

Comment: Instead of having two layouts, one for portrait and one for landscape you can have a single parameterzied layout (e.g. controlling pading or other attributes) and get the parameters from res/values and res/values-land respectivly. This way you don't need to repeat the common aspeptcs of the two layouts.

Answer (score 0):

When screen orientation changes, it will start from onCreate() again. So you can check what is your current orientation of screen in onCreate() and then dynamically set the height and width of your view.  keep your xml code as it is only set dynamically the height width of your view  when it is in landsacpe.